# Magento 2: How to solve an error when reindex by CLI?

Tags: magento2, error, reindex, composer, cli

I used Magento 2 stable version. when I run Magento `setup:upgrade`, following error occurred.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.
```

And when I run Magento `indexer:reindex`, also error display

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "indexer" namespace.
```

How to resolve this? Any other solution to reindex without CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reindex Magento 2 using the command.

Now You have to enter this command in your root installation folder.

```
sudo php -f ./bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

please clear folders **di, page_cache, view_process , cache.**

restart your command prompt and try to re-index.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Can i reindex by admin without use of cli ?

Comment: you have to set up cron job for this.

Comment: i didnt understand  `Your path like var\www\html\magento2\bin`
how to reindex with my path and are you using \ instead of / or is it on purpose?`

Comment: it is magento root folder path...

Comment: @denishvachhani. how can i use `sudo` in windows CLI

Comment: in windows no need to use 'sudo' at all direct run command.

Comment: `sudo php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento indexer:reindex` would work too, if you prefer to do everything in one step

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had wrong DB info in `app/etc/env.php`

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but incase anyone arrives here looking for answers: most `There are no commands defined` errors are down to not running them as `sudo`